# tensor-board inconsistent line graph colour

Tags: pytorch, tensorboard

I'm using tensorboard to analyze a number of experiments. Each time i am comparing two experiments. Tensorboard seems to assign orange and blue to each experiment. However for some reason when i compare different colour the order of the colour is assigned change so If A was blue and B orange. some experiment seems to chagne A to orange to B to Blue. I would like to keep the same colour so it easy to refer to them in my re-writing up. I have tried to rename the event files in order to change the colour but that didn’t work. Is there any way to change the order of the way tensorboard assign the colour to the graphs? or how does assign the colour? I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance